# GetView + Intent Param Object Error

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, adapter, getview

I have this problem now: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object .. Class Filho implements serializable. How to solve?

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
{
    final Filho filhoPosition = this.listaFilhos.get(position);
    view = LayoutInflater.from(this.context).inflate(R.layout.lista_filho,null);

    TextView textViewNomeFilho = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewNomeFilho);
    TextView textViewTelefoneFilho = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewTelefoneFilho);
    ImageView imageViewFotoFilho = (ImageView)  view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewFotoFilho);

    textViewNomeFilho.setText(filhoPosition.getNome());
    textViewTelefoneFilho.setText(filhoPosition.getTelefone());
    imageViewFotoFilho.setImageBitmap(filhoPosition.getFoto());

    final ImageButton imageButtonConfigFilho = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonConfigFilho);
    imageButtonConfigFilho.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            filho = new Filho(filhoPosition.getIdFilho(),filhoPosition.getNome(),filhoPosition.getTelefone(),filhoPosition.getFoto(),filhoPosition.getLoginConfig());

            Intent it = new Intent(context, CadastrarFilhoActivity.class);
            it.putExtra("filho",filho);
            context.startActivity(it);
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Comment: implement `Parcelable` in `Filho`. Using android studio will help need not write code yourself IDE will generate stuff for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `Filho` class implements `Serializable` .It is a common problem

That is go to `Filho` class and implement `Serializable`

```
public class Filho class implements Serializable
```

### Edit

Use intent like this you are using `putExtra()`

```
Intent it = new Intent(context, CadastrarFilhoActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("filho",filho);
it.putExtras(bundle);
```

and get by this in `CadastrarFilhoActivity.class`

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
Filho filho=(Filho)bundle.getSerializable("filho");
```

Comment: The class is already implementing serialization but gives this error

Comment: I ended up finding that the problem is because it has a Bitmap in the child class when I put it as null in the instance of the object it works but when passing the Bitmap parameter the error happens

Comment: @LeonardoInhoqui then you can convert bitmap to base64 and pass

Comment: I solved the problem by trading private Bitmap photo by transient Bitmap photo. Tanks

Comment: @LeonardoInhoqui Glad to hear that you got a solution. But do not thank me, brother. Happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If I put the 4 parameter that is a bitmap like null works, for some reason the bitmap field is giving this problem because I'm not new to java and android and I have no idea how to solve

```
it.putExtra("filho",new Filho(filhoPosition.getIdFilho(),filhoPosition.getNome(),filhoPosition.getTelefone(),filhoPosition.getFoto(),filhoPosition.getLoginConfig()));
```

Comment: I am new android but I will look for an alternate way